# copy value of a list into another within a method in python

Tags: python, list

```
x = []        
p = []       

def init():
    for _ in range (n):
         x.append(random())
    # loop end here

    p = x[:]
    # or
    p = deepcopy(x)
# init method end here
```

In this scenario, I want to exact copy of x into p. but after calling function x list has n elements but p is empty list. I don't know how to copy x value into p. I wrote `global p`

Comment: Please fix indentation!

Comment: global p?  init() is changing local p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, you're creating a new local object `p` with a copy of `x`, but leaving the global `p` intact. If you want to mutate the global list `p`, this is probably the best way to do it:

```
p[:] = x
```

Essentially, it means **"replace everything in p with all the items from x"**

Comment: There's also the option of including `global p` before the assignment.

Comment: @JAB ... which would change `p` to point to a new object instead of changing the existing one. Both could be the right thing to do, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Yes, but this is *less global*. i.e. if you're a function in a function, this modifies the parent function's local `p`, rather than a global

Comment: `global` should never be an option.

Comment: @Matthias Depending on the circumstances. If you want modular behavior, it probably isn't a good idea, but if you're just using it in a script to execute then it's perfectly fine to use, just as how you may sometimes want to use `nonlocal` when designing a closure.

Comment: Why not pass `p` in as an argument?

Comment: @2rs2ts, if you have `p = ` anywhere in the function, even when p was passed as an argument, it'll be locally scoped

Comment: `p[i] =` will not localize `p`, so in that sense yes, but as you've written it there are other errors

Comment: `p[:] = x` would suffice, no need to copy the items *twice.*